# Selling a Joomla extension with third party jquery plugin

Tags: licensing, gpl

Let's suppose I want to create an extension for Joomla that uses a jQuery plugin or any third party library. Imagine that I create a Joomla module that uses jquery Nivo Slider plugin (MIT License) http://nivo.dev7studios.com/license/. I'm not sure If I could sell this module with this license.

Could I sell it if the plugin has a GPL License?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GPL, You can *sell* anything, as long as the whole product is under GPL as well. GPL doesn't prevent you from asking money for stuff, it prevents you from preventing users the four freedoms that the GPL is trying to grant. The GPL license doesn't ask you to give stuff away for free, it asks you to also provide the source along with the code and let your users use the product as they please (as long as that usage still complies with the GPL).

With MIT, you can do almost anything with the library, including bundling the code in a proprietary, closed source application/extension/library.

Comment: Thanks Sergiu for your quick answer! You have helped me to clarify my problem